# writeOGR error: creation of output file failed

Tags: gdal, rgdal

I'm an R rookie and attempting to create home ranges from fish telemetry data using  kernel density estimates within the adehabitatHR package

```
    kud <- kernelUD(muskydetectdata.P[,6], h="href", extent = 5)
    class(kud)

    image(kud)
    kud[[1]]@h

    muskykud.P95 <- getverticeshr(kud, percent = 95)
    muskykud.P95 

    muskykud.P50 <- getverticeshr(kud, percent = 50)
    muskykud.P50
```

when exporting to a shapefile

```
    writeOGR(muskydetectdata.sp,"musky_kde1", "gps", 
    driver="ESRI Shapefile",                                        
    dataset_options= "FieldName= id")
```

an error message is displayed

```
    ##creation of output file failed
```

I have also attempted to use `writeSpatialShape` with similar results

I'm using R version 3.3.2 on windows 64 bit

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and have solved it only when I added a full name of my directory and a name of a layer plus a shp suffix:

```
writeOGR(muskydetectdata.sp, dsn="d:/your directory here/musky_kde.shp", layer="musky_kde", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: This was my problem. Specifically, and critically, it turned out that I was using the ~ symbol to abbreviate my save directory. Don't do that with writeOGR or you'll get this error message also.

Comment: "layer" should be lower-case

Answer (score 1):

I had that same error.

I resolved mine by correcting the directory it was saving to (making sure it existed)

e.g.

```
writeOGR(muskydetectdata.sp, dsn = save.dir, layer = filename.save, driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

where save.dir is the directory you want saved as a string and filename.save is the filename you want it saved as (excluding extension)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to write on an existing file and the `writeOGR` function don't allow that. I guess this is a known behavior of some drivers supported by OGR (as far as I remember in R as in python and in the C API).

You have to check if the file exists prior to your writing and removing it (or changing the path you want to use).

For example here the first write operation succeed but the attempt to overwrite the file fails with your error message :

```
> rgdal::writeOGR(spdf, 'b.shp', layer="brazil", driver='ESRI Shapefile')
> rgdal::writeOGR(spdf, 'b.shp', layer="brazil", driver='ESRI Shapefile')
Error in rgdal::writeOGR(spdf, "b.shp", layer = "brazil", driver = "ESRI Shapefile") : 
  Creation of output file failed
```